# Checking Database Server/Client User

Tags: java, swing, jetbrains-ide

I have an Java application which has Server and a Client user.
What I want to know if there's a way to Notify the Server or the Client user
That someone updated the table.
For example the Client has updated a field in database,
In the Server User, the table must be updated automatically.(No Refresh needed)
I am thinking of using timer but i think it will lag the application.
I am using JetBrains and Java Swing for my App.

Comment: Java Messaging Service (JMS) is one API / service that's available as a part of some databases (such as redis) but which otherwise you could employ as part of your enterprise solution

Comment: I am using MySql server. Will that work?

Comment: Need to look into whether it supports any messaging services by default... I don't know that it does, but maybe things have changed. Even if it doesn't, you can use JMS through web services you create that add or change information in your DB

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to consider using the "Observer" design pattern, you can start reading about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).